# Proof Rules in Set Theory

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

This is probably a very dumb question, but I can't see where am I going wrong.

So Let F be formula, where $F \equiv xy = 5.$

Prove that $ \forall x F \vDash y = 5 $.
Using the proof Rules,
 If $ S ∪ {[F]x→t}\vDash G $  Then $ S ∪ {∀x F} \vDash G $, where t is a term

$ [F]x→1 \equiv 1 * y = 5$, * is multiplication.

Assuming we are in a field, it is easy to show
$ S ∪ {[F]x→1} \vDash y = 5 $. , where S is a premise set that contains the field axioms

Then 
$ S ∪ {∀x F} \vDash G $. But it is easy to see that if x = 2, then y is 5/2.
What did I do wrong. I know it is probably very dumb, but I cant see it.

Comment: Is this really _set theory_? Your description of what you're doing is quite confusing (for example you speak of "proof rules" but write $\vDash$ instead of $\vdash$, and $\vDash$ is about semantics not proof), but none of it appears to be about sets. Do you have any axioms that give meaning to the multiplication (I assume) operation and the symbol $5$?

Comment: I am assuming that we are in a field. I am sorry which semantics are confusing. I am not really good with the editor.

Comment: Yeah it is a multiplication symbol; i shouldve noted that.

Comment: So you have the field axioms? And are you supposed to prove $\vDash$ or $\vdash$?

Comment: I am really sorry what is the difference, I was taught that  S ⊨ G, means that G is a consequence of the premise set S. Yes, I have the field axioms.

Comment: $S\vDash G$ means that $G$ is true in every structure that satisfies $S$. $S\vdash G$ means that there is a formal proof of $G$ using the assumptions $S$.

Comment: Then I am pretty sure it is S⊢G.

Comment: Like i am supposed to prove ⊢.

Comment: I'm afraid I still see little rhyme or reason in what you're doing. Generally in a field you can prove that $\forall x(x\cdot t_1=t_2)$ requires $t_1=t_2=0$, if $x$ does no occur in $t_1$ or $t_2$ -- but I don't really see anything in what you write that looks like it belongs in a proof of that ...

Comment: So basically, what I am confused about is that in the proof rules, they say If $ S ∪ {[F]x→t}\vDash G $  Then $ S ∪ {∀x F} \vDash G $. And what i am showing is a contradiction (and i know what i did is wrong). So what i did is find a formula above and show that and applied the proof rules to prove $ S ∪ {∀x F} \vDash G $. Which is clearly wrong, if we are in a field.

Comment: Are you using a textbook, or notes? Could you provide a link or snapshot of the proof rules you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring various notational trouble, you have correctly proved that if you assume the field axioms plus $\forall x(xy=5)$ then you can conclude $y=5$.

You have also *almost* correctly concluded from the same assumptions that $y=5/2$ (the reason that this is only almost correct is that you need $2\ne 0$ in order to be able to divide by $2$, and your assumptions do not guarantee that).

So the assumption $\forall x(xy=5)$ leads to the two apparently conflicting results $y=5$ and $y=5/2$. But so what? *A priori* there are at least two ways this can make sense:

- **Either** $\forall x(xy=5)$ simply *cannot be true in the first place*. In that case it should not surprise you that you can prove nonsense from it.
- **Or** your conclusions are not actually nonsense. It could be that you find yourself in a field where $5=5/2$, and then there's no contradiction after all.

The second of these is what's actually happening. In $\mathbb F_5$ or another field of characteristic $5$ we do indeed have $5=5/2$ because both sides are actually zero! And $\forall x(xy=5)$ is true exactly if we're in a field of characteristic $5$ and $y$ happens to be $0$.

Comment: Wow, I thought my proof is completely bogus. I didnt even know what characteristics are.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me, but this is the notation we are taught in.